# Does filecmp do an exact comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, compare

[`filecmp.cmp` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html) states (emphasis mine)

> Compare the files named *f1* and *f2*, returning `True` if they **seem** equal, `False` otherwise.
> If *shallow* is true, files with identical `os.stat()` signatures are taken to be equal. Otherwise, the contents of the files are compared.

What does *seem* mean here? My understanding is that for `shallow=False` the contents of the files are compared, and therefore files are unambiguously either the same, or not.

Comment: The answers to the question [`filecmp.cmp()` ignoring differing `os.stat()` signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045564/filecmp-cmp-ignoring-differing-os-stat-signatures) I once asked may clarify things for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code is fairly straightforward; there's a link to it in the documentation page for the `filecmp` module, at the top:

```
def cmp(f1, f2, shallow=True):
    """Compare two files.
    Arguments:
    f1 -- First file name
    f2 -- Second file name
    shallow -- Just check stat signature (do not read the files).
               defaults to True.
    Return value:
    True if the files are the same, False otherwise.
    This function uses a cache for past comparisons and the results,
    with cache entries invalidated if their stat information
    changes.  The cache may be cleared by calling clear_cache().
    """

    s1 = _sig(os.stat(f1))
    s2 = _sig(os.stat(f2))
    if s1[0] != stat.S_IFREG or s2[0] != stat.S_IFREG:
        return False
    if shallow and s1 == s2:
        return True
    if s1[1] != s2[1]:
        return False

    outcome = _cache.get((f1, f2, s1, s2))
    if outcome is None:
        outcome = _do_cmp(f1, f2)
        if len(_cache) > 100:      # limit the maximum size of the cache
            clear_cache()
        _cache[f1, f2, s1, s2] = outcome
    return outcome

def _sig(st):
    return (stat.S_IFMT(st.st_mode),
            st.st_size,
            st.st_mtime)

def _do_cmp(f1, f2):
    bufsize = BUFSIZE
    with open(f1, 'rb') as fp1, open(f2, 'rb') as fp2:
        while True:
            b1 = fp1.read(bufsize)
            b2 = fp2.read(bufsize)
            if b1 != b2:
                return False
            if not b1:
                return True
```

So yes, it will compare the file contents.